# Shiny - issue with renderTable for > 2,000 rows dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

Shiny > renderTable seems to struggle with "large" data.frame.
The code below works perflectly well

```
output$raw <- renderTable({
head(data, 2000)
```

})

But with 7000 rows to display:

```
output$raw <- renderTable({
head(data, 7000)
```

})

Shiny is able to display everything but then it seems I am "loosing my application" (as if I lost connection or an error did occur) and then I end up with a grey screen.

I have also had a look at renderDataTable which seems faster but also suffers from the same issue with too large data.frames

Is there any way / options within shiny to deal with this issue?

Many thanks!